# PlaceHolder When Users connects to my chromecast application

Tags: casting, chromecast

How to show Placeholder on chromecast receiver Device whenever user connect connects to chromecast from my application. I want to show my logo whenever user connects to the chromecast. In hotstar and Youtube whenever user connects to the Chromecast the receiver application shows the logo of corresponding app on the screen.

Answer (score 1):

You need to write a custom receiver and take advantage of the receiver api [onSenderConnected()](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/reference/receiver/cast.receiver.CastReceiverManager#onSenderConnected) and show whatever info you have and desire.

Comment: I used the styled media receiver and provided a custom skin(css file) but it not getting updated when casting from phone. In preview it is showing fine. How much time it takes to see the effect.